# F12 like shortcut in Visual Studio to jump from a unit test directly to the code (through the _accessor)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>F12</kbd> is an awesome shortcut to jump to the implementation of a method/member.

Unfortunately when using the Unit Testing from Visual Studio it creates a Class_accessor file and I can't jump through it.

So when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> on MyClass_accessor.MyMethod() I'd like to get to MyClass.MyMethod and not the _accessor interface/mock.

Any ideas how to jump from a unit test directly to the code (through the _accessor)